# How can I determine where the include paths are coming from?

Tags: c++, clang++, include-path

I'm familiar with the trick of adding `-v` to the Clang compile command line to see the include search path order, but that just shows which directories are being searched. It doesn't show *why* those directories are being searched.

Is there some option to print verbose information about where the include search path settings are coming from? (e.g. command line options, environment, compiled-in settings, etc.) -- Any settings which give more information about why they're in the order they're in would also be appreciated.

Note that I'm not wondering where a particular include file is coming from (e.g. the information you can get with `-M` or `-H`), I'm interested in why the compiler is searching a particular include *path*.

---

*Background: We're trying to debug why a particular path (/usr/local/include) comes "too high" on the list of search directories for a particular platform (Mac 10.14). We don't* think *our build system is explicitly requesting it, so knowing more about where it's coming from would help us figure out what's going on.*

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not a duplicate - I'm not interested in where the header *file* is coming from, I'm interested in where the include *path* is coming from. `-M` (or `-H`) will tell me that `foo.h` is being found at `/path/to/libdir/foo.h`, but it won't tell me why the compiler is looking in `/path/to/libdir` in the first place.

Comment: @R.M. Well, try some search like [this](https://www.google.de/search?q=c%2B%2B+determine+oder+of+include+search+paths&oq=c%2B%2B+determine+oder+of+include+search+paths&aqs=chrome..69i57.13221j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), maybe this would give you better results. (Disclaimer: This was by no means meant to diminish the OP or saying LMGTFY, I am just trying to help solving the problem).

Comment: it checks the following env vars: `CPATH`, `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH`, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, `OBJCPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, the command line `-I` directives and probably some compiled in system search paths...

Comment: According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html, it seems the default search path is configuration dependent. What is the output for the command given in the link?

Answer (score 2):

How the clang default include paths are chosen is nowhere documented. It (and also gcc for Mac) apparently does not follow [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html). It is documented for clang how [these can be managed](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#include-path-management).